# Ошибка при обращении к элементу массива

Tags: c#, массивы, исключения

При запуске программы

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] listNames = new string[4] { "Личный", "Рабочий", "Семейный", "Список книг" };
        TodoList[] TodoLists = new TodoList[listNames.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < TodoLists.Length; i++)
        {
            TodoLists[i].name = listNames[i];
        }
    }
}

class TodoList
{
    public string name;
    public string[] tasks;
}
```

получаю ошибку

> `Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at dz.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Yuri\source\repos\dz\dz\Program.cs:line 15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TodoList[] TodoLists = new TodoList[listNames.Length]` лишь создаёт массив на `listNames.Length` элементов, в каждой ячейке которого лежит `null`.

Вам сначала нужно проинициализировать элементы массива, чтобы с ними работать.

```
TodoList[] TodoLists = new TodoList[listNames.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < TodoLists.Length; i++)
{
    TodoLists[i] = new TodoList();
    TodoLists[i].name = listNames[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < TodoLists.Length; i++)
{
    TodoLists[i] = new TodoList() { name = listNames[i] };
}
```